# Using jQuery tmpl in Wordpress and problem with ${ data} placeholder

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-templates

I am going to use jQuery.tmpl on the WordPress page.
Everything is going well until I apply the template over JSON Array.
My problem is with placeholders.
WordPress doesn't recognize the $ sign and iteration doesn't render ${placeholder}.

Do you have any suggestions?

This is the code:

```html
<script id="brokersTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
  <div class="data"> ${itemId} </div>

</script>
<div id="brokerResolve"></div>

<script>

jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
    jQuery.getJSON('data.json', function(jd) {
      jQuery('#brokersTemplate').tmpl(jd).appendTo('#brokerResolve');
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: Please consider I am working on Wordpress page. Wordpress themes have problem with using the $ sign.
I don't want to use noConflict and don't want to enable using $ versus jQuery.

Comment: I have mentioned this on my subject and also in my question body. How I can use string literal in Wordpress while I donot want to use $?